# Protractor with directConnect to Firefox times out randomly

Tags: firefox, webdriver, protractor

I have a protractor installation which runs every 10 minutes. I'm using Firefox with directConnect because I need to set a user agent, and I can't use chrome since it fails if two instances of protractor are run concurrently.

At least once a day, a timeout occurs:

```
Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:89
          Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
          ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:50162/hub
    at Error (native)
    at onResponse (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:89:11)
    at /u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:44:21
    at /u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/http/http.js:140:5
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:172:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:259:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
    at new Driver (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:277:36)
    at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:75:16)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:182:37)
    at /u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:263:21
    at _fulfilled (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /u01/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Versions:
Protractor 2.5.1 (Selenium WebDriver 2.47.0)
Node v4.2.2
Firefox 38.2.1

protractor.config.js

```js
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var firefoxProfile = new firefox.Profile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", 'monitoring7758932056');
firefoxProfile.setPreference('startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional', 'about:blank');
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'firefox_profile': firefoxProfile
    },

    suites: {
        login: 'login.spec.js',
    },

    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.100:8080/application',

};
```

login.spec.js

```js
describe( 'login', function () {

        var loginPage;

        beforeEach( function () {
                loginPage = require( './LoginPage.js' );
        } );

        it( 'should let a user to login', function () {
                loginPage.get();
                loginPage.loginAsTestUser();
                expect( login.isCurrentPage() ).toBe( false );
        } );

} );
```

LoginPage.js

```js
function LoginPage () {

    function get() {
            browser.get( '' );
    }

    function loginAsTestUser () {
            element( by.model( 'username' ) ).sendKeys( 'user' );
            element( by.model( 'password' ) ).sendKeys( 'password' );
            return element( by.xpath( '//button[@type=\'submit\']' ) ).click();
    }

    function isCurrentPage() {
            return element( by.model( 'password' ) ).isPresent();
    }
}
module.exports = new LoginPage();
```

How can I avoid these timeouts?

Comment: What protractor and firefox versions are you using? Also, please show your protractor config and the test you are running. Thanks!

Comment: I added versions, config and tests. Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround, I implemented a script which runs the test again if it fails. This does not solve the original problem, but it is enough for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly setting the firefox profile, it's not that simple. There is a [`setFirefoxProfile`](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile) how-to that shows how to set firefox preferences via making a custom firefox profile.

Comment: I tried it and it is using my profile. I verified it used my user agent. Do you think my way could be creating some race condition? I also checked webdriver source, and I found that they use two versions of profile: a serialized form (as in the howto) and a plain object profile (as my example). Protractor just passes the capabilities object to the constructor.

Comment: @narduk I can be wrong. Could you please throw me the link where you've found this way of setting up a firefox profile? Thanks.

Comment: I just looked up protractor and webdriver sources. Protractor: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/direct.js :75 Webdriver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js :234

Comment: @narduk okay, but can you try following the `setFirefoxProfile` example and set the profile the way suggested? Thanks.